# Slow & memory leak when looping MD5 calculations

Tags: java, performance, memory, garbage-collection, md5

I have asked a similar question here [Performance issues when looping an MD5 calculator on many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244691/performance-issues-when-looping-an-md5-calculator-on-many-files), but I realized that the problem is not the code, but the GC, so I needed a new page for the same problem, but with a different kind of solution.

I'm running an MD5 calculation loop on 1000+ image files. The program tournes slow after about 200, and uses a lot of memory (free -> inactive). It uses as much memory I had free when I started it (2GB-5GB).

I tried to use Java.io / FastMD5. This code is the latest test with Java.nio.
The problem occurred on all of them, and even FastMD5, which is an external library, so the problem is not the way I calculate the MD5, apparently.

The problem seems to be the fact that the code runs so fast that the GC doesn't have time to keep up with the objects.

**Are there any optimizations to the GC or my code that can help me with my memory problem?**

**EDIT** Tried to use ThreadLocal. No go. I realized that the program is somehow caching the MD5s, because after a slow loop (with a memory leak) comes a fast loop with no memory leak. After I release the memory the program goes slow again (and then fast).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File[] directory = new File("/Users/itaihay/Desktop/Library/Seattle 2010").listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < directory.length;i++){

        System.out.println(Utils.toMD5(directory[i]));

        }
}
```

Utils.toMD5():

```
  public class Utils {


public static final ThreadLocal<MessageDigest> mdT = new ThreadLocal<MessageDigest>(){
   protected MessageDigest initialValue(){
        try {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
       return null;
   }
};

public static final ThreadLocal<ByteBuffer> bufferT = new ThreadLocal<ByteBuffer>(){
    protected ByteBuffer initialValue(){
            return ByteBuffer.allocate(32000);
    }
};

private static Utils util = new Utils();
private static MessageDigest md;
private static FileChannel fileChannel;
private static ByteBuffer buffer = bufferT.get();

private Utils() {

//            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md = mdT.get();

}
public static String toMD5(File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
//        BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

   RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

    fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();

    /*while (fileChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
        buffer.flip();
        md.update(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    }*/

    while (fileChannel.read(bufferT.get()) != -1) {
        bufferT.get().flip();
        md.update(bufferT.get());
        bufferT.get().clear();
    }

    byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

    randomAccessFile.close();
    bufferT.get().clear();
    mdT.get().reset();

    return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(mdbytes)
            .toLowerCase();

}
```

Comment: Should you be using the `MD5` over and over again?  Wouldn't it better to create a new one each time you need it (ie at the start of each new check)??

Comment: This code is wrong at the very least you need to call `md.reset()` before calculating an md5. And it is certainly not thread safe.

Comment: Use `jvisualvm` to determine what is using the memory. I would suspect it is the `MessageDigest` but couldn't say for sure.

Comment: @BevynQ I tried jvisualvm. It's inconclusive. The MD5s are saved to memory. No idea Why.
See the edited post. Tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MD5` object is growing without bounds as you never reset it, as @BevynQ observed, and ditto your code isn't thread-safe. You must use method-local `MD5` and `ByteBuffer` objects. Use a much bigger `ByteBuffer`, e.g. 32k or more, to make it go faster.

You don't need to close both the `RandomAccessFile` *and* the `FileChannel`: one will do.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. No go. See the edited post.
The program somehow saves the MD5s to memory, because after one slow run with a leak comes a fast run w/o leaking.

Comment: You didn't try it at all. I repeat. You must use method-local MD5 and ByteBuffer objects. The edited code is still stuffed full of static members.